# Initialize SKShapenode from subclass?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a subclass of SKShapeNode called "Character", I'm trying to initialize it using rectOfSize, however I cannot due to `Must use designated initializer`.

I've been reading about this mechanic but I don't really get how to initialize my SKShapeNode. I believe the only designated intializer from SKShapeNode is `init()`.

How can I initialize it as if I had used `rectOfSize: CGSize(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)`

This is what I tried:

```
class Player: SKShapeNode {
     init() {
        super.init(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)) // Must use designated initializer
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, post it in an answer so I accept it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a bug. I doubt all of those initializers should be convenience. For now you can either A) Declare no initializer so the initializers get inherited. B) Use the init designated initializer and manually set the path of your shape node using something like: self.path = ...

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this (my example is for circleOfRadius):

```
class Hunterer: SKShapeNode {

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        let rectSize:CGFloat = 2.0 * RootSGA.specificsHunterRadius()
        let rectSizeHalf:CGFloat = rectSize / 2.0

        let r = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(-rectSizeHalf, -rectSizeHalf), size: CGSizeMake(rectSize, rectSize))
        self.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(r, nil)
        self.alpha = RootSGA.ArenaCommonObjectsAlpha
        self.fillColor = RootSGA.HunterBackground
        self.strokeColor = RootSGA.HunterBackgroundEdge
        self.lineWidth = RootSGA.HunterBackgroundEdgeWidth
        self.glowWidth = RootSGA.HunterBackgroundEdgeGlowWidth
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 class Player: SKShapeNode {
        override init() {
            super.init() 
        }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }

    // For create a Player with init(rectOfSize)

    var player : Player
    player = Player(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of **SKShapeNode subclass** with property and custom initializer:

```
class MyNode: SKShapeNode {
    let playerType: PlayerType

    init(size: CGSize, playerType: PlayerType) {
        self.playerType = playerType
        super.init()
        self.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)).cgPath
        self.strokeColor = (playerType == .player) ? .orange : .darkGray
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```